# How do I create a class that always is the same instance of itself and is used keep track of variable values?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

So I want to outsource all important variables to a new class.
A non working example to showcase what I'm trying to do would be this:

```
public class GameState{
    public bool ToggleA{ get; set; }
    public bool ToggleB{ get; set; }
    public int a{ get; set; }
    public int b{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I "keep this class alive" once a value was set and make everything refer to the same instance?
My google searches led me Singleton patterns
([Link](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx), however that didn't bring me further, either I didn't understand how to implement what I want to do into them properly, in that case, an in-depth example would be neat, or I need to use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement this is indeed using the singleton design pattern.  It will allow your code to remain testable.

Given the following interface:

```
public interface IGameState
{
  bool ToggleA { get; set; }
  bool ToggleB { get; set; }
  int A { get; set; }
  int B { get; set; }
}
```

The following is a singleton implementation of it:

```
public class GameState : IGameState
{
  // This instance variable will only ever have one copy instantiated
  private static GameState _instance = new GameState();

  // Private constructor so the class cannot be instantiated outside of the class.
  // This ensures that no other class can create an instance of the class.
  private GameState() { }

  public static GameState Instance { get { return _instance; } }

  public bool ToggleA { get; set; }
  public bool ToggleB { get; set; }
  public int A { get; set; }
  public int A { get; set; }
}
```

You can now inject this singleton wherever you need it, which will maintain the test-ability of your code.

```
public class SomeObject
{
  private IGameState _gameState;
  public SomeObject(IGameState gameState)
  {
    _gameState = gameState;
  }

  public void SomeOperationOnGameState()
  {
    _gameState.ToggleA = true;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:  Updating to explain test related comments**

Imagine that your GameState object evolves has a complex method for performing a calculation, and that you want to ensure that this method is called when necessary.  If you are using a global static class, there is no way to verify this behavior.  If you are programming to an interface however you can mock out this dependency using a mocking framework and verify that the complex method was indeed called.

For example, we are going to extend the `IGameState` interface to the following:

```
public interface IGameState
{
  bool ToggleA { get; set; }
  bool ToggleB { get; set; }
  int A { get; set; }
  int B { get; set; }

  int ComplexStateAlteringMethod();
}
```

Now imagine you have some sort of Controller class, that manages key presses:

```
public class Controller
{
  private IGameState _gameState;
  public Controller(IGameState gameState)
  {
    _gameState = gameState;
  }

  public void KeyPressed(string key)
  {
    // Implementation details go here, say you want to call the complex method when the 'A' key is pressed
    if (key == "A")
    {
      _gameState.ComplexStateAlteringMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

You want to ensure that when the 'A' key is pressed, the `IGameState.ComplexStateAlteringMethod()` is called.

Without explaining mocks, i'll create a Stub `IGameState`:

```
public class StubGameState : IGameState
{   
  public bool ToggleA { get; set; }
  public bool ToggleB { get; set; }
  public int A { get; set; }
  public int B { get; set; }

  public bool WasStateAlteringMethodCalled { get; private set; }
  public void ComplexStateAlteringMethod()
  {
    WasStateAltermingMethodCalled = true;
  }
}
```

Now you can use this stub class can be used to verify the behavior you are looking for (Assuming NUnit is the testing framework):

```
[TestFixture]
public class ControllerTests
{
  [Test]
  public void KeyPressed_WhenAIsPressed_ShouldCallStateAlteringMethod()
  {
    // Arrange
    var stub = new StubGameState();
    var controller = new Controller(stub);

    // Act
    controller.KeyPressed("A");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(stub.WasStateAlteringMethodCalled);
  }

  [Test]
  public void KeyPressed_WhenBIsPressed_ShouldNotCallStateAlteringMethod()
  {
    // Arrange
    var stub = new StubGameState();
    var controller = new Controller(stub);

    // Act
    controller.KeyPressed("B");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(stub.WasStateAlteringMethodCalled); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! Could you explain what you mean with the code remaining testable? Could you give an example how using Broken Pixels solution could cause problems?

Comment: @Charles how would you test the singleton if it wasn't injected?  You could access the instance without referring to its interface.

Comment: I've updated to show you could use the singleton pattern to ensure you could test your code.

Comment: @brumScouse You have to inject the Singleton to maintain testability, but if you use a static global container, nothing you do will allow you to test the code.

Comment: @Charles. If injecting using DI/IOC, couldnt we just set the lifetime/scope of the instance to be a singleton?  I feel that the classic implementation of the singleton here, is leaky as we dont actually need the interface to access it.

Comment: @brumScouse Yes you could, I'm not really getting into using an IOC container here.  The OP is asking for an explanation of the Singleton pattern though, so figured I would throw it all out there.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a static class.

```
public static class GameState ...
```

Static classes only have a single instance. You don't `new` them. You access them via the class name:

```
GameState.ToggleA = true;
DoStuff(GameState.b);
```

etc.

Each of your properties have to be static too:

```
public static bool ToggleA {get;set;} ...
```

Static classes are essentially equivalent to the Singleton pattern in this case.

Comment: If I do it like this I don't get any options when I do Gamestate.~ besides Equals and ReferenceEquals

Comment: Edited, I forgot to mention, sorry.

Comment: This is not testable...  If you have to have a class that only ever have one instance, singleton is the way to go.

Comment: @CharlesGraham What do you mean? Static classes can only have a single 'instance', by definition.

Comment: @BrokenPixels I mean that if you use a global static class like this, it is basically just a container for global variables, and that any class that depends on it cannot be unit tested, because you cannot mock the dependency.  The resulting code is highly coupled with the static class.

Comment: @CharlesGraham unless there's no need to mock it in the first place, of course. Also, a singleton would **not** have been "less coupled". You perhaps mean that a static class cannot implement an interface (in C#) and therefore you cannot inject a different dependency for an interface. However, singletons do not /by definition/ introduce such an interface.

Comment: @CharlesGraham That is fair, I see your point. However, I think a solution which allows for mocking and unit tests is outside the requirements of a question that is essentially asking how to create a global object.

Comment: @sehe No they don't, and yes I mean if you properly design your singleton and inject the dependency (not necessarily with an IOC container).  If you use a global static class, you will be tempted to add stuff to it, and then you are on a slippery slope.

Comment: "If you use a global static class, you will be tempted to add stuff to it" - this is completely based. That's like saying, if you have some code, you'll be tempted to write more code. Yes, it's a slippery slope :/